# The Index value from Map method is not changing in Nested DropDown in React JS - Material UI

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu, material-ui, jsx, menuitem

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    makeStyles,
    Typography,
    InputLabel,
    Grid,
    Paper,
    TableContainer,
    Table,
    TableHead,
    TableRow,
    TableBody,
    TableCell,
    TextField,
    FormControl,
    Select,
    MenuItem,
    Button,
    Menu,
} from '@material-ui/core';
import PlayCircleFilledIcon from '@material-ui/icons/PlayCircleFilled';
import NestedMenuItem from 'material-ui-nested-menu-item';

const MainTable: React.FC = () => {
    const classes = styles();

    const [sentence, setSentence] = React.useState<any>([]);
    const [menuPosition, setMenuPosition] = React.useState<any>(null);
    const [emotionIntensity, setEmotionIntensity] = React.useState<any>([{}]);
    const sentences = [
        '1Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi, nobis. Ab placeat provident aliquid sequi assumenda amet commodi. Ipsam cum ab totam sapiente delectus quam distinctio, ratione ducimus explicabo modi!',
        '2Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi, nobis. Ab placeat provident aliquid sequi assumenda amet commodi. Ipsam cum ab totam sapiente delectus quam distinctio, ratione ducimus explicabo modi!',
        '3Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi, nobis. Ab placeat provident aliquid sequi assumenda amet commodi. Ipsam cum ab totam sapiente delectus quam distinctio, ratione ducimus explicabo modi!',
        '4Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi, nobis. Ab placeat provident aliquid sequi assumenda amet commodi. Ipsam cum ab totam sapiente delectus quam distinctio, ratione ducimus explicabo modi!',
        '5Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi, nobis. Ab placeat provident aliquid sequi assumenda amet commodi. Ipsam cum ab totam sapiente delectus quam distinctio, ratione ducimus explicabo modi!',
    ];

    const emotionArr = [
        'Neutral',
        'Pleasant',
        'Relaxed',
        'Elated',
        'Surprise',
        'Angry',
        'Depressed',
        'Fatigue',
        'Unpleasant',
    ];

    const intensityArr = ['Low', 'Medium', 'High'];

    React.useEffect(() => {
        setSentence(sentences);
        // creating an array of sentence size
        const updatedEmotionIntensityArr = [...emotionIntensity];
        for (let i = 0; i < sentence.length; i++) {
            updatedEmotionIntensityArr[i] = {};
        }
        setEmotionIntensity(updatedEmotionIntensityArr);
    }, []);

    const handleChangeSentence = (i: any) => (event: any) => {
        // console.log('sentence is', event.target.value);
        const updatedSentences = [...sentence];
        const updatedSentence = event.target.value;
        updatedSentences[i] = updatedSentence;
        setSentence(updatedSentences);
    };

    const handleClick = (event: React.MouseEvent) => {
        if (menuPosition) {
            return;
        }
        event.preventDefault();
        setMenuPosition({
            top: event.pageY,
            left: event.pageX,
        });
    };

    const handleItemClick =
        (emotion: any, intensity: any, sentenceIndex: any) =>
        (event: React.MouseEvent) => {
            setMenuPosition(null);
            console.log('Index No is ', sentenceIndex);

            const myNewArray = Object.assign([...emotionIntensity], {
                [sentenceIndex]: {
                    emotion,
                    intensity,
                },
            });

            console.log(myNewArray);
            setEmotionIntensity(myNewArray);
        };

    return (
        <Grid container alignItems='center' justify='center'>
            <Paper className={classes.root}>
                <TableContainer className={classes.container}>
                    <Table stickyHeader aria-label='sticky table'>
                        <TableHead>
                            <TableRow>
                                {columns.map((column) => (
                                    <TableCell
                                        key={column.id}
                                        align={column.align}
                                        style={{ minWidth: column.minWidth }}
                                    >
                                        {column.label}
                                    </TableCell>
                                ))}
                            </TableRow>
                        </TableHead>
                        <TableBody>
                            {/* First Row, will make it dynamic */}
                            {sentence.map(
                                (sentenceString: any, sentenceIndex: any) => {
                                    return (
                                        <TableRow key={sentenceIndex}>
                                            {/* sentence */}
                                            <TableCell>
                                                <Grid
                                                    container
                                                    direction='row'
                                                    justify='center'
                                                    alignItems='center'
                                                >
                                                    <TextField
                                                        required
                                                        id='sentence'
                                                        name='sentence'
                                                        spellCheck='false'
                                                        classes={{
                                                            root: classes.textField,
                                                        }}
                                                        value={sentenceString}
                                                        multiline
                                                        inputProps={{
                                                            style: {
                                                                textAlign:
                                                                    'left',
                                                                paddingTop:
                                                                    '0.5rem',
                                                                paddingLeft:
                                                                    '0.5rem',
                                                                fontFamily:
                                                                    'Comfortaa',
                                                                minWidth:
                                                                    '450px',
                                                            },
                                                        }}
                                                        onChange={handleChangeSentence(
                                                            sentenceIndex
                                                        )}
                                                    />
                                                    <PlayCircleFilledIcon />
                                                </Grid>
                                            </TableCell>
                                            {/* This Problem is in this cell */}
                                            <TableCell>
                                                {/* <NestedMenu /> */}
                                                <Button
                                                    variant='outlined'
                                                    onClick={handleClick}
                                                >
                                                    Emotions
                                                </Button>
                                                <Menu
                                                    open={!!menuPosition}
                                                    onClose={() =>
                                                        setMenuPosition(null)
                                                    }
                                                    anchorReference='anchorPosition'
                                                    anchorPosition={
                                                        menuPosition
                                                    }
                                                >
                                                    {emotionArr.map(
                                                        (emotion) => {
                                                            return (
                                                                <NestedMenuItem
                                                                    label={
                                                                        emotion
                                                                    }
                                                                    parentMenuOpen={
                                                                        !!menuPosition
                                                                    }
                                                                    key={
                                                                        emotion
                                                                    }
                                                                >
                                                                    {intensityArr.map(
                                                                        (
                                                                            intensity
                                                                        ) => {
                                                                            return (
                                                                                <MenuItem
                                                                                    onClick={handleItemClick(
                                                                                        emotion,
                                                                                        intensity,
                                                                                        sentenceIndex // this index value does not change
                                                                                    )}
                                                                                    key={
                                                                                        intensity
                                                                                    }
                                                                                >
                                                                                    {
                                                                                        intensity
                                                                                    }
                                                                                </MenuItem>
                                                                            );
                                                                        }
                                                                    )}
                                                                </NestedMenuItem>
                                                            );
                                                        }
                                                    )}
                                                </Menu>
                                            </TableCell>
                                        </TableRow>
                                    );
                                }
                            )}
                        </TableBody>
                    </Table>
                </TableContainer>
            </Paper>
        </Grid>
    );
};

export default MainTable;
```

The `sentenceIndex` that I'm passing in the `handleItemClick` is not changing. Rather than iterating as the number of elements in the `sentences` array, the key value does not change. I have used this index in another table row and it is working fine, the value is iterating but using it with `NestedMenuItem` and `MenuItem`, the key value does not change. I cannot find exactly what is causing the `sentenceIndex` to not iterate according to the elements present in the `sentences` array.

Comment: When ``sentenceIndex`` reaches the Menu Component, its value stops changing (I used an onClick method to see the index value on console). I do not understand why's the value getting struck when it reaches the Menu Component